# Troubles monitoring a zimbra installation with nagios

Tags: perl, sudo, zimbra, nagios

I am trying to monitor my legacy zimbra installation (running on an outdated Ubuntu 8.x) from my nagios install (running on a more recent OpenBSD).

The problem is that when I run `check_nrpe` from the nagios server it complains:

```
nagios-server$ sudo su -m _nagios -c "/usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_nrpe -H ZIMBRA_HOST -c check_zimbra"
CHECK_NRPE: No output returned from daemon.
```

Note that the zimbra server's NRPE configuration runs:

```
command[check_zimbra]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_zimbra.pl
```

On the other hand, running the plugin locally on the zimbra server works fine from root:

```
zimbra-server# ./check_zimbra.pl 
HOST : ZIMBRA_HOST, ldap : OK, logger : STOPPED and zmlogswatchctl down, mailbox : OK, mta : STOPPED and zmmtaconfigctl down and zmsaslauthdctl down, snmp : STOPPED, spell : OK, stats : OK
```

However, running it as nagios user on the zimbra server complains about the path:

```
zimbra-server# su -m nagios -c "./check_zimbra.pl" 
Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running setuid at ./check_zimbra.pl line 32.
```

Line 32 recites:

```
7  $zimbra_status_command='/opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol status';
[snip]
32 open (ZMSTATUS, "$zimbra_status_command |");
```

I have a suspicion it might have something to do with **suid perl**. In fact, following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552197/insecure-envenv-while-running-with-t-switch) and adding this line to the `check_zimbra.pl` file,

```
delete @ENV{'PATH', 'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};
```

I get the following:

```
zimbra-server# su -m nagios -c "./check_zimbra.pl" 
Insecure dependency in piped open while running setuid at /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol line 389.
```

Anyhow, on the zimbra server I have installed the [check_zimbra.pl](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Email-and-Groupware/check_zimbra-2Epl/details) plugin, which is `suid` zimbra so I can run it from the `nagios` user:

```
zimbra-server# ls -la check_zimbra.pl 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 zimbra root 2885 2010-01-11 21:14 check_zimbra.pl
```

I have modified `/etc/sudoers` so that the `nagios` user can run the appropriate zimbra monitoring tool:

```
%nagios ALL=(zimbra) NOPASSWD:/opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol
```

I am stuck.. is there any other way to run the `check_zimbra.pl` plugin as nagios user, being able to run the `zmcontrol status` command as zimbra user..?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

perldoc perlsec states that should set @ENV{'PATH'} to a known value, not unset it !

> Blockquote
>   For "Insecure $ENV{PATH}" messages, you need to set $ENV{'PATH'} to a known value, and each directory in the path must be
>          absolute and non-writable by others than its owner and group.  You may be surprised to get this message even if the pathname to
>          your executable is fully qualified.  This is not generated because you didn't supply a full path to the program; instead, it's
>          generated because you never set your PATH environment variable, or you didn't set it to something that was safe.  Because Perl
>          can't guarantee that the executable in question isn't itself going to turn around and execute some other program that is
>          dependent on your PATH, it makes sure you set the PATH.